# _layout.cshtml logout button not updated after logging out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to logout from a web site but my _layout.cshtml does not get updated till I do a refresh of the website.

What I basically try to accomplish is that after I clicked on logout, I want to get redirected to the logout page and get the login button shown again. Right now, I only can get one thing of it working.

1. I redirect to the home controller -> Login button gets shown
2. I redirect to the logoff page -> Logoff button still visible

My cshtml looks like that:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, true, new { id = "logoutForm", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
    }
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
```

and my logout function:

```
[HttpGet, Route("[controller]/Logout")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
    {
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "For some reasons, HTTP context is null, signing out cannot be performed"
        );
    }
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(AccountController.Logout), "Account");
    //return Redirect(nameof(AccountController.Logout), "Account");
    return View();
    //return RedirectToAction("~/ControllerName/ActionName");
    //return Redirect("Logout");  
    //return LocalRedirect("~/");
}
```

I tried different return types but without any luck

Comment: I think only when `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`,it will show the logout button,maybe you can try to check if the use is IsAuthenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword. With that I could find the code: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User =
                    new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
After setting that I receive the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `Logout` view:

```
@{
    ViewData["signed-out"] = true;
}
```

Then in `_Layout.cshtml` check like this:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !true.Equals(ViewData["signed-out"]))
{
}
else
{
}
```

I found this pattern in `IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI`, you can see it being used in [`LoggedOut.cshtml`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/main/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml) and [`_Nav.cshtml`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/main/Views/Shared/_Nav.cshtml).

Comment: Hi,
I tried your solution but it did not work. But what was working is adding: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User =
                    new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);